# Extract an alphanumeric from sentence

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have an VBA to extract an alphanumeric value from a column G which is a sentence.

This sentence is generally a comment. So it includes characters and numbers.

The value always starts with `AI0` and ends with `0`. This can be 11 to 13 digits long. Sometimes the number is mentioned in the comment as `AI038537500`, also sometimes as `AI038593790000`.

I have researched through almost all the websites, but have not found any case like this. I know about the formulas, `left`, `right`, `mid` but in my case, it doesn't apply.

[image: If you notice, here i have in comment section the Id with AI0 and Ends with 0. I want to extract this ID to result column.]

Any lead would be appreciable.

Comment: You can use `Instr` to find the position of the first occurrence of "A10" and then use it again to find the first "space"  after that position.

Comment: Also, will there ever be a case of a string `A100`, or `A10299A1000`?  Can you show an example of the output? From `A1038537500`, do you want to extract `A103853750`?

Comment: I will post an Picture of how i want my Output.

Comment: @BruceWayne i have posted an Image. if it is not clear, Please let me know

Comment: *"always starts with A1O and ends with 0. This can be 11 to 13 digits long"*... Your example does not conform to this. I'm lost.

Comment: @A.S.H it was just to clarify that there are charchters only in the begining and not at the end. If it is confusing,then i am sorry, i will post an another one.

Comment: @Mikz, so `0` at the end is optional?

Comment: optional in the sense.  it should be considered @Rushikumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give something like the following a try?

```
Sub findMatches()

    Dim strLength As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count

        Dim AllWords As Variant
        AllWords = Split(Cells(i, 7).Value, " ")

        For Each Item In AllWords


            strLength = Len(Item)
            If strLength > 0 And strLength <= 13 And Item Like "A10*?#" Then
                Cells(i, 8) = Item
            End If

        Next

    Next i

End Sub
```

**Test Cases:**

1. I am apple and my batch number is: A10545440 so incase you needed to know

**Result:** A10545440

2. Some random comment… A20548650

**Result:** *NO RESULT*

3. A101234567891 is an awesome alphanumeric combo

**Result:** A101234567891

4. Another random comment… A10555

**Result:** A10555

Notice: The above example covers cases where the alphanumeric combo, starting with `A10` is either:

- In the middle of a sentence, or
- Beginning of a sentence, or
- At the end of a sentence

Also note: right now it is set to go through ALL the rows... so if you want to limit that, change the `Rows.Count` in the `For` statement to whatever your set limit is.

**EDIT:**
In the above code, I am explicitly asking it to look in column G

Comment: @ rushikumar i get an userdefined type not defined error there.

Comment: @Mikz, updated the code to take into consideration your requirements of 13 characters and I was not matching the pattern... you will still need to tweak that while I try and come up with the correct match

Comment: @Mikz, you are missing the reference, most likely... so go to `Tools --> References` and check the checkbox for `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0`

Comment: @Mikz, okay... yet another update to the code... simply changed `Like "A10"` to `Like "A10*?#"` That should do it!

Comment: I added the reference, and the code is running. But  i dont ´find any result. It is just running without Errors. also, i want to print the value in another column if it is found in comment.

Comment: @Mikz, are you sure your data is in G column? The code runs just fine on my end... the only thing it is missing is extracting that value... which I am in the process of updating the code

Comment: Ya ,I am sure that the data is in column G.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147285/discussion-between-mikz-and-rushikumar).

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this...

Place the following User Defined Function on a Standard Module and then use it on the sheet like

```
=GetAlphaNumericCode(A1)
```

**UDF:**

```
Function GetAlphaNumericCode(rng As Range)
Dim Num As Long
Dim RE As Object, Matches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "AI\d{9,}0"
End With
If RE.Test(rng.Value) Then
   Set Matches = RE.Execute(rng.Value)
   GetAlphaNumericCode = Matches(0)
Else
   GetAlphaNumericCode = "-"
End If
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you give this a try? I think it should do the job, also you should ammend the code with the column values, I tested it with the comments being in column C, while the code will be written in column D.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub FindValue()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lFirstChr As Long
    Dim lLastChr As Long
    Dim CodeName As String

    lastrow = activesheet.Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' gets the last row with data in it

    For i = 1 To lastrow
    ' shuffles through all cell in data

    lFirstChr = InStr(1, Cells(i, 3), "A10") ' gets the coordinate of the first instance of "A10"

    If lFirstChr = 0 Then GoTo NextIteration

    lLastChr = InStr(lFirstChr, Cells(i, 3), " ") ' gets the coordinate of the first instansce of space after "A10"

      If lLastChr = 0 Then 'if there is no space after A10 then sets lastchr to the lenght of the string

            lLastChr = Len(Cells(i, 3))

        End If

    CodeName = Mid(Cells(i, 3).Value, lFirstChr, lLastChr - lFirstChr) ' extracts the codename from the string value

    Range("d" & i).Value = CodeName

    Goto NextTteration


    NextIteration:
       Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: there is an runtime error "invalid procedure call or Argument" in the line 
    lLastChr = InStr(lFirstChr, Cells(i, 7), " ")

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code I had "A1O" instead of "A10", also do you have any data other than the comments in the column?

Comment: Still the error exist. Could you Please comment the Explanation, near the code . It would be easy to understand

Comment: It seems like Rushikumar's solution is much more sophisticated, but I realized the problem might be in the lastrow = worksheet("munka1".Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row which was referencing the sheet I worked on, I changed it to the activesheet.